# Get result from Calculator with WScript.Shell

Tags: python, windows

I wanted to get a result of operation from Calculator, but can't find any special functions.
Here's my code:

```
import win32com.client
import win32api
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("calc")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.AppActivate("Calculator")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.SendKeys("1{+}")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("2")
win32api.Sleep(500)
```

And then I want to get the result from calc and compare it with if_then, like

```
if calc_result== 3:
    print ("True")
else:
    print ("False")
```

I'm working on Python 3.3.2 and it's my first steps. Thank you.

Comment: Is this just an exercise in using the win32api? Because otherwise there are probably way better ways to do whatever it is you're trying to do ;)

Comment: Yes, it's an exercise with win32api :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing, there might be better ways, but you can send <kbd>=</kbd> click followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> as `1{+}2{=}^C` so you copy it to the clipboard and then read it using Windows clipboard functions, something like:

```
import win32com.client
import win32api
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("calc")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.AppActivate("Calculator")
shell.SendKeys("1{+}2{=}^C")
win32api.Sleep(500)

import win32clipboard
import win32con
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
r = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT).rstrip('\x00')
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
print(r)
```

preview:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> import win32api
>>> shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
>>> shell.Run("calc")
0
>>> win32api.Sleep(100)
0
>>> shell.AppActivate("Calculator")
False
>>> shell.SendKeys("1{+}2{=}^C")
>>> win32api.Sleep(500)
0
>>>
>>> import win32clipboard
>>> import win32con
>>> win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
>>> r = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT).rstrip('\x00')
>>> win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
>>> print(r)
3
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it's close to right solution, but I've got an issue. I'm working on Win7 and value of r is '20.6\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...'.

Comment: @stvieG Try to do `r.rstrip('\x00')` to remove these null bytes, I updated the code now.